# Solve equation with summation and factorial over Integers

Tags: equation-solving, findinstance

Find all $\{ m, n \} \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^m k! = n^2 .$$

The two solutions are $\{ m,n \} = \{ 1,1 \}$ and $\{ 3,3 \}$, as can be confirmed.  [Here is how to solve this problem mathematically](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGHFIb42PHc).  I seek to solve it using computer symbol manipulation (and preferably not through exhaustive search.)

The obvious approaches do not work:

```
Solve[Sum[k!, {k,1,m}] == n^2 && {m, n} > 0, {m, n}, Integers]
```

and

```
FindInstance[Sum[k!, {k,1,m}] == n^2 && {m, n} > 0, {m, n}, Integers]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ask it at MSE. This is rather math than Mathematica.

Comment: I know how to solve it mathematically.  (Michael Penn solved it on his Youtube channel.)  I want to know how to do it in *Mathematica*.

Comment: In each of your `Sum`s, the summand should be `k!` vice `n!`. However, that does not resolve the issue. A brute force approach: `Select[Flatten[Table[{m, n}, {m, 1, 100}, {n, 1, 100}], 1], Sum[k!, {k, 1, #[[1]]}] == #[[2]]^2 &]`

Comment: @BobHanlon:  Typo fixed.  Thanks.  (I had it correct in my computational attempts.).  I was very much hoping to avoid brute force... especially given that a mathematical approach solves the problem.  Moreover, *big* problems of this sort would require enormous computer power.

Comment: The command `FindInstance[Sum[k!, {k, 1, m}] == n^2 && {m, n} > 0, {m, n}]` results in `{{m -> 1, n -> 1}}`.

Comment: `Solve`, `Reduce`. `Minimize`, and `FindMinimum` all promptly convert `Sum[k!, {k,1,m}]` to `-1 - Subfactorial[-1] + (-1)^(1 + m) Gamma[2 + m] Subfactorial[-2 - m]`, which apparently is correct.  However, if the `Reals` or `Integers` domains are specified, these functions eventually realize that `Subfactorial[-1]` is complex and quit with an error message.  I view this as a bug, because this internal error should not leak out.  In fact, it occurs even for the trivial `SolveValues[Sum[k!, {k, 1, m}] == n, n, Reals]`.

Comment: @user64494:  Interesting.  When I restricted the `FindInstance` to `Integers` I do NOT get a solution, but when you don't restrict, then you *do* get a solution.  Weird, since the solution must be integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `QuadraticResidues` resource function https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/QuadraticResidues/

```
QuadraticResidues[5]
(* {0, 1, 4} *)
```

Thus, 3 is the *quadratic nonresidue* (*mod* 5).

Next, observe that this comes at contradiction with the property of the LHS for $m>4$:

```
f[m_] := Sum[k!, {k, 1, m}]
Table[Mod[f[m], 5], {m, 15}]
(* {1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3} *)
```

This fact is easy to see from $n!=0\,(\text{mod}\, 5)$ for $n\ge5$.

Thus, the only possibility $m=1$ and $m=3$. Now solve the equation

```
Solve[f[1] == n^2 && n > 0, n, Integers]
Solve[f[3] == n^2 && n > 0, n, Integers]
```

Notice that for completely automatic solution it is necessary that MA "knows" quadratic residues in some simple cases. Currently besides the resource function, this in not available.

Comment: Wow... I never would have come across that clever approach on my own.  Thanks so much.  ($+1$).  Actually, because this is the most *symbolic* approach:  $\checkmark$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thank you! Really appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Numerical solution with `NMinimize / NMaximize`  .

```
su[m_?NumericQ] := NSum[k!, {k, 1, m}, NSumTerms -> m]

nmin = NMinimize[{n, {m >= 1, m \[Element] Integers, n >= 1, 
n \[Element] Integers, (su[m] - n^2) == 0}}, {m, n}]

(*   {1., {m -> 1, n -> 1}}   *)

nmax = NMaximize[{n, {m >= 1, m \[Element] Integers, n >= 1, 
n \[Element] Integers, (su[m] - n^2) == 0}}, {m, n}]

(*   {3., {m -> 3, n -> 3}}   *)
```

Comment: Interesting approach... I certainly hadn't thought of that.  Thanks.  ($+1$)